# Searching in crontab

Tags: cron, search

I'm pretty new to ubuntu and cron, and I was wondering how to search for something in the crontab file. Basiclly, the ubuntu equivilent of ctrl+f on windows.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

just found it. If I run crontab -e, I can search with ctrl+w.

thanks for the help

Comment: Ah, you did not mean *the* crontab file (/etc/crontab), but the user specific crontab entries. If you set your EDITOR to gedit, you will have nicer output and be able to use Ctrl-F.

Answer (score 3):

To grep a user-specific crontab:

`crontab -l | grep -i keyword`

Answer (score 1):

Try from command line. Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run following command :

```
cat /etc/crontab | grep yoursearchkeyword
```

Comment: This crontab file doesn't appear to be the one I get when I use `crontab -e`

Answer (score 0):

You can just open the crontab file in gedit and use Ctrl-F.

```
gedit /etc/crontab
```

For your user specific crontab file, do

```
crontab -e
```

Depending on your $EDITOR environmental variable, you will open it in your favorite editor. If the EDITOR=gedit, then you will be able to do Ctrl-F. If the editor is nano, you need to do Ctrl-W. With EDITOR=vi, you type /.

Comment: Is there anyway to `cat` the user-specific crontab?

Comment: sudo cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/username | grep -i searchterm